# PHP variables and anchors in URL

Tags: php, html

I can't find a solid answer on this, and trial and error is getting me nowhere.

I have am generating a dynamic PHP page with variables in my URL, so my URL looks like:

```
http://www.mypage.com/myfile.php?l=1&d=1&c=1

(works)
```

I'd like to also add an anchor to this, such as:

```
http://www.mypage.com/myfile.php?l=1&d=1&c=1#anchor1
(Does not jump to the anchor at the end)
```

The anchor is targeting a div such as:

```
<a href = "http://www.mypage.com/myfile.php?l=1&d=1&c=1#anchor1">Some link</a>
<div id = "anchor1"></div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What does *Does not work* mean? And you should always include the protocol at the beginning of your links (`http://`, `https://` or `//`)

Comment: The page sits still, and does not jump to the anchor.

Comment: Thanks.  Just taking short cuts to post here, http:// is actually in there.  I'll edit to match.

Comment: Are you sure there's an element with `id="anchor1"` in that page? And make sure that it isn't created with javascript after page loads

Comment: The id is also dynamically generated, but yes, I've checked to make sure that it is named correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This should work better

```
<a href="http://www.mypage.com/myfile.php?l=1&d=1&c=1#anchor1">Some link</a>
<div>
    <a name="anchor1"></a>
</div>
```

Note that the right way of doing it depends on what doctype you are using. You can read more about this for [html5 here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#scroll-to-fragid) and for [html 4.01 here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/intro.html#fragment-uri)

Comment: I don't think the name should have # in it?

Comment: Just as a note: The `&` in URLs should be encoded.  `http://www.mypage.com/myfile.php?l=1&amp;d=1&amp;c=1#anchor1`

Comment: Leave HTML 4.01 behind, and move towards HTML5! The `name` attribute is obsolete in HTML5, `id` should be used instead

Comment: @Oriol It might be obsolete but it's still valid. It will check for name if there is no element in the DOM that has an ID exactly equal to fragid.

Comment: I'm actually using html5, I should have clarified that, however, still having no luck with the "id"

Answer (score 0):

Some Browsers, will not automatically target your `id`, based on the URL hash. You may consider using JavaScript.

```
var doc = document;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function offset(element){
  var x = 0, y = 0, e = element;
  while(e && !isNaN(e.offsetLeft) && !isNaN(e.offsetTop)){
    x += e.offsetLeft - e.scrollLeft;
    y += e.offsetTop - e.scrollTop;
    e = e.offsetParent;
  }
  return {left: x, top: y};
}
function YourSolution(listId){
  var parentId = E(listId), pcn = parentId.childNodes;
  for(var i=0,l=pcn.length; i<l; i++){
    if(pcn[i].nodeType === 1){
      var ac = pcn[i].childNodes;
      for(var n=0,m=ac.length; n<m; n++){
        var an = ac[n];
        if(an.nodeType === 1){
          an.onclick = function(){
            var el = offset(this);
            scrollTo(el.left, el.top);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Put the above on an external JavaScript page called `scroll.js`. Now put the following code at the bottom of your `body`:

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='scroll.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    YourSolution('listId');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using chrome, but if it is possible that it wouldn't work in other scenarios, could you please provide an example of how to accomplish w/ JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to implement this.  The href is being put dynamically on a list item in a for each loop which I'm attempting to anchor to a div that is later produced dynamically as well.  Can you please explain how this should be used?  I'm not very familiar with implementing JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that the id is added dynamically.

Then, you can refresh the hash AFTER adding the id and appending your element to the document

```
var h = location.hash;
location.hash = '';
location.hash = h;
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/wpMDj/1/show/#anchor

**Code**: http://jsfiddle.net/wpMDj/1/

---

Alternatively, you can use [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollIntoView):

```
document.getElementById(location.hash.substring(1)).scrollIntoView(true);
```

But to avoid errors you need some ifs:

```
var hash = location.hash.substring(1);
if(hash){
    var el = document.getElementById(hash);
    if(el && el.scrollIntoView){
        el.scrollIntoView(true);
    }
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/wpMDj/3/show/#anchor

**Code**: http://jsfiddle.net/wpMDj/3/

Comment: I've found that changing the `location.hash` when dealing with dynamically generated content doesn't always work well.  `window.setTimeout(function() {document.getElementByid("hash1").scrollIntoView(true)}, 1);` works reliably for me.